# MultiFieldQueryParser fuzzy searching

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I'm trying to implement a fuzzy search which takes a string like "Samsung Galaxy S7 tablet" and searches across multiple fields (Category, Brand, Model), but I'm unable to set the sensitivity of the fuzzy query.

The following code

```cs
    var line = "Samsung Galaxy S7 tablet";
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48);
    
    string[] searchfields = new string[] { "Category", "Brand", "Model" };

    var query = new BooleanQuery();
    var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, searchfields, analyzer);
    string[] terms = line.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach (string term in terms)
    {
        var q = parser.Parse(term.Replace("~", "") + "~0.8");
        query.Add(q, Occur.MUST);
    }
```

always produces a query like
`+(Category:samsung~2 Brand:samsung~2 Model:samsung~2) +(Category:galaxy~2 Brand:galaxy~2 Model:galaxy~2) +(Category:s7~2 Brand:s7~2 Model:s7~2) +(Category:tablet~2 Brand:tablet~2 Model:tablet~2)`

Any idea how can I set the sensitivity of the fuzzy query. Is there a better way to perform this type of search using Lucene?

Thank you!

Comment: were you able to find any solution?